# Android AutoCompleteTextView NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, autocompletetextview

I am trying to create an auto complete text input field with AutoCompleteTextView. But when i start the app, it breaks and the log file reports the NullPointerException.

In the onCreate I have:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
     (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, codes);  
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actvPrompt); 
    if(actv == null) {
        Log.e("MyApp", "actv is null");
    }
    actv.setAdapter(adapter); // This line throws exception.
```

in the xml layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actvPrompt"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

I checked the 'codes' array, and it's populated fine.

Why is actv null?

Comment: Could you also post logcat error report?

Comment: can you upload full file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're missing `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` in `onCreate()` or you're not doing it **before** `findViewById()` or you're using a different layout.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this :

```
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//This is your layout<-----

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
     (YourClass.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, codes);  


   AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actvPrompt); 
      actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also try to change your XML for this :

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/actvPrompt"
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this keyword you have to use ClassName.this

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
     (Classname.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, codes);

Comment: No, `Classname.this` is only necessary if his code in inside an inner class and needs to reference the parent class's `this`. This is not the case here.